# PHP header redirect - Not Working

Tags: php, html

This is the code:

```
if($rowCheck>0) {
  session_start();

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check)) {
    $_SESSION['developer'] = $row;          
  }

  header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/index.php");
}
else
    echo 'Invalid Password or Email!';
```

Everything is working fine except the `header`, and if i write an `echo` after the `header` it will work normally. Also if i printed the `location`, it will show me the exact and right `location`.

I'm running on mamp and macos. So it's on a localhost.

Any help ?

Comment: make sure error reporting is turned on. What error messages do you get?

Comment: What is that loop doing? It won't do what you think it should.

Comment: Where is the "{" after the "else" statement ? btw wich error do you get ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV { } aren't required for a single line.

Comment: @samsamX hate spaghetti code ~_~

Comment: Are you doing something like `die()` or `exit()` later on that is killing the script before it writes the header? Or doing something funny with output buffering?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV I agree with you ;)

Comment: @EvanMulawski That loop is working perfectly fine and i got all the row in the session. I used it on the index page and it worked normally.

Comment: Try to change header to print. Do that print out something?

Comment: @vascowhite It prints the location, in localhost.

Answer (score 1):

As scott said, you need the exit() or die() after the header.

Also, check that there are no empty spaces before or after your opening and closing php tags, like this:

```
   <?php
```

That will cause header functions to fail, as it is considered input. Any related include files should be checked as well.

Comment: I already fixed it before. AS you mentioned, there was a white space bfore the php tags.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 0):

just comment everything and paste at the right beginning `header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/index.php");` and see if it is working. If not, check for a BOM encoding.

Comment: I did this, I commented everything and wrote the header only in the file, it doesn't redirect. What's BOM encoding ? I'll google it now,

Comment: Check your file encoding within your text editor. You ahve to save it under the UTF8-NOBOM format (the name might change according to your text editor)

Comment: It was set as UTF8. NOBOM is not available under my text editor "Coda".

Comment: well then I don't know... If you have a "UNIX" encoding select it, to see?

Comment: Still same issue, really strange.

Comment: could you try `<?php header("Location: http://www.google.com"); ?>` as the only content of your php file¿?

Comment: Sorry for the later reply, but all this problem was because of a white space before <?php

Answer (score 0):

Add exit() or die() after the header line. The header function does not stop execution of the rest of the script.

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: nothing same, blank page !! If i print the location it prints the location. Also if i write any code after the header it works fine and If i delete all the code in the login.php and enter the header, it doesnt redirect... On the other hand the Logout.php has a header to the index page same one, and it works.

Comment: You haven't turned on output buffering have you?

Answer (score 0):

Couple things.

First I would put `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the very top of your page within the PHP code.  You may be getting a "headers already sent" error.

Add an exit after the header to keep the script from going any further:

```
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/index.php");
exit;
```

Lastly this bit doesn't make sense.

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check)) {
    $_SESSION['developer'] = $row;          
  }
```

You're setting that session variable once so you don't need the while. You're also setting it equal to a mysql resource (which you may intend to do), but maybe you just need a column

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
$_SESSION['developer'] = $row['username'];
```